# Display data from 2 table - Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I try display data from table Course and Test, the relation is one-to-many.

```
course name   | test name  
___________________________
course name1  | test name 1     
course name2  | test name 2
```

etc.

```
public $table = 'Course';

public function test()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Test');
}


public $table = 'Test';

protected $fillable = ['name',];

public function course()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Course');
}
```

TestController.php

```
public function courses() {

 $courses = Course::with(['test'])->get();,
 return view('admin.test.list_course', [
              'courses' => $courses,

         ]);
 }
```

list_course.blade.php

```
 @foreach($courses as $course)

        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ $course->name }}
            </td>

            <td>
             {{ $course->test->name }}
            </td>         

        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

And I get error

> Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance

Please, do you anybody know where is error? Thank you!!

Comment: And which line in your code causes this error

Comment: in blade  {{ $course->test->name }}

Comment: Have you tried $course->test['name'] or $course->{'test name'}?

Comment: yes, i got error syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Comment: {'test name'} display empty rows

Comment: As you Want one-to-many relation it will return a collection. To display it in the View you have to loop through all tests that belong to the course

@foreach($course->test as $test)
{{$test->name}}
@endforeach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `test` relation on the Course Model is a one-to-many relation, meaning that there can be more than one test for every course, because of this the relation will return a `collection` of all tests belonging to the course.
To display it in the View you could loop through all tests:

```
@foreach($courses as $course)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ $course->name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            @foreach($course->test as $test)
                {{ $test->name }} <br>
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can I ask you on more thing please.. I try display question count. course name | test name | question count . I have relation between Test and Question 1:N . how can I do this, pls? In my Testcontroller, i have $courses = Course::with(['test'])->get();
        $questions = $courses->question;

Comment: Could you accept this answer and make a completely new question, so you can explain better what the new problem is.